# Setting height of multiple textarea elements in javascript on load

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, object, textarea

On a webpage I am to set the height of several textarea elements to match their content. I've tried different approaches like

```
var textarea = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');

$(document).ready(function(){
    for(var i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++){
    console.log("textarea="+textarea[i]);
  $("textarea").height( $("textarea")[i].scrollHeight );
}
});
```

But this sets the height of the first element to the height of the last element as can be seen [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ux7hx4eu/1/).

How can I ensure that every textarea element on the page gets its height set to fit the content on load?

Answer (score 2):

Try using the `.each()` JQuery function to loop through all your textareas combined with the selector  `this` to select the right `textarea` :

```
$(function(){
    $('textarea').each(function(){
        $(this).height($(this)[0].scrollHeight );
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("textarea").height` will change the height of *all* textareas on the page simultaneously, hence why you're getting the effect that it sets them all to the height of the last one.

It's easier if you don't mix jQuery and JS syntax:

```
var textAreas = $("textarea"); //get textAreas as a jQuery object

//loop through all the jQuery textarea objects
textAreas.each(function(index, element) {
  var textArea = $(this); //select only the current textArea in the loop
  textArea.height(textArea.get(0).scrollHeight); //.get(0) gets the underlying HTML element which has the scrollHeight property
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$("textarea")` finds all textareas on your page. So by setting `$("textarea").height` it will set the height of all. As such only the last change is actually kept.

Instead we can loop over the array and only adapt the current textarea. This can be done with basic javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var textareas = document.querySelectorAll('textarea');
    for(var i = 0; i < textarea.length; i++){
        textarea[i].style.height = textarea[i].scrollHeight + "px";
    }
});
```

See it working in this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ux7hx4eu/3/).

I know my solution is not as clean as using jQuery's `.each()` but it's easy to understand and it's nice to have for users that do not use jQuery. (note however that then the `$(document).ready(function() {` should be replaced by `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {`